# Office Communicator 2005 Application Sharing on Windows 7 x64 not working

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ms-office-communicator

Since moving to Windows 7 x64 at work, Office Communicator 2005 will no longer allow me to do application sharing with other users on our domain. IM, file transfer, and video chat all work fine, but I consistently get the following message when I try to invite or accept an invitation for Application Sharing:

> {Username} does not have data sharing
>   session installed (or it is disabled)
>   and is not able to accept your
>   invitation.

Has anyone else experienced this problem or having working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is what I've learned:

1. Application Sharing also does not work on the 32-bit version of Windows 7
2. Apparently this doesn't work on Vista, either.

From [this blog post](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2009/09/win_7_and_office_communicator.html), I've learned that Communicator 2005 depends NetMeeting, which isn't supported in Vista or Win 7. (Seems that there was a hotfix to make this all work under Vista, but it doesn't support Win7 yet.)

So, it looks like I'll have to wait until they upgrade to our server to *Communication Server 2007*.